# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

While running my code I get the error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.yahoo.astra.fl.charts.series::LineSeries/drawMarkers()
    at com.yahoo.astra.fl.charts.series::LineSeries/tweenUpdateHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.yahoo.astra.animation::Animation/timerUpdateHandler()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

It does not specify any line where this error occurs.How this error can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You application is probably not running in debug mode or the swf for the yahoo components is compiled in release mode, so that's why you don't see line numbers.

Comment: How this can be solved..I am very new to this as3.Can you please specify how it can be removed?